# does money map to float well?

Tags: c#, sql-server, types

does the sql data type money map to c# float?

Comment: Also mrblah you have a pretty high point count.  Before posting questions like this google it or even search for this same exact question.  It has been asked hundreds of times.

Comment: @JonH: Search on SO, by all means. But it was never intended that SO should be your *second* choice after Google. This site was specifically designed to make Google searches unnecessary. To give people *one* trustworthy site to get answers from, rather than relying on Google pointing us to hundreds of different and unreliable sites.

Comment: @jalf - My point is search is necessary rather then posting a simple simple question.  Besides if you search in google there is a fairly large chance that the result will point you here.  If you're in the middle of coding and you need something real quick there is nothing wrong with googling.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No...it maps to a `decimal`. If the column allows null, it maps to `Nullable<Decimal>`.

[Mapping CLR Parameter Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx)

`float` isn't precise enough to be used for monetary calculations. You'd be losing/gaining money all over the place.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use decimal.

> The Decimal value type represents
>   decimal numbers ranging from positive 
>   79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335
>   to negative
>   79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335.
>   The Decimal value type is appropriate
>   for financial calculations requiring
>   large numbers  of significant integral
>   and fractional digits and no round-off
>   errors. The Decimal type  does not
>   eliminate the need for rounding.
>   Rather, it minimizes errors due to
>   rounding.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Money maps to [Decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx).  If the MONEY column allows null values, it will map to `Nullable<Decimal>.`  For details, see [SQL-CLR Type Mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386947.aspx).

Float is not nearly precise enough for numerical computations dealing with money.  You should always do all of your calculations using decimal values.

Answer (score 1):

No, a `float` has way too low precision to handle monetary values. Seven digits doesn't get you far. Also a floating point type is prone to rounding errors due to how the numbers are represented.

Use the `Decimal` data type.